# zeros and convergence or divergence in iterations

Tags: complex-analysis, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

I'm solving some numerical analysis exercises and I still can not find a way to solve the following

Consider the function $f (x) = x^3 - x - 1$. For the equation $f (x) = 0$ answer the following:

.

1. If we rearrange $f(x)=x(x^2-1)-1$, we arrive at the iteration:

   $x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{x_n^2-1}$

   When reorganizing $f (x) = (x-1)(x^2+x+1)-1$ we obtain:

   $x_{n+1} = 1 + \frac{x}{x^2+x+1}$

   demonstrate the equivalence of these two expressions.
2. How do these iterations behave? (Take start point $x_0 = 1.5$ and calculate some $x_n$ values).
3. Analyze the convergence or divergence of the previous interactions near zero $x$*.

How should I do it to get to the right way?

Comment: You can with any method find some approximation for $x^*$. The execution of task 2 with 10-20 iterations should also not be too difficult, you have a computer, thus you have some scripting language or a spreadsheet calculator available. Please do that and report your results. For task 1 you need to do exactly what is demanded, show that $f(x_n)=0$ if and only if $x_{n+1}=x_n$, which is the equivalency.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. Regarding task 1 I have doubts. What do you mean by showing that $ f (x_n) = 0 $ and that $ x_ {n + 1} = x_n $ the task is done ?, with what method could you demonstrate this?
Thank you very much again

Comment: You have to show that the fixed points of the iterations are exactly the roots of the polynomial. There is no method involved, just an interpretation of the factorizations that are given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding 1, taking into account that the first expression is not defined for $x=1$, the expressions are only equivalent for $x \ne 1$.

Regarding 3, just recall that the fixed point theorem establishes local convergence when $|g'(x^*)|<1$, and almost sure divergence when $|g'(x^*)|>1$. In the first case,
$$
|g'(x^*)| = \left|\dfrac{-2x^*}{((x^*)^2-1)^2}\right|>1
$$
and so you conclude  that the fixed point iterations will diverge unless, by pure luck, one of the iterations hit $x^*$.

In the second case, this iteration function is continuous, invariant and contractive in $[1,2]$ and therefore the iterations will converge to $x^*$ for any $x_0\in [1,2]$. Moreover, considering that $|g'|\leq 3/49$, we can say that
$$
|x_n-x^*| \leq (3/49)^n |x_0-x^*| \leq (3/49)^n.
$$

Comment: How do you get from $g'(x)=\frac{-2x}{(x^2-1)^2}$ to your formula for $|g'(x^*)|$? I get $g'(x^*)=-2(x^*)^3=-2(x^*+1)$, which still proves the point but is a different formula.

Comment: @LutzL you are correct, I'll update the post.